# Use glm with data.table and a parametric definition of the predictors and the response

Tags: r, data.table, glm

I want to do VIF testing running consecutive regressions within a dataset, each time using one variable as the response and the remaining as predictors.

To that end I will put my code within a for loop which will give consecutive values to the index of the column that will be used as the response and leave the remaining as predictors.

I am going to use the data.table package and I will use the mtcars dataset found in base R to create a reproducible example:

```
data(mtcars)
setDT(mtcars)
# Let i-- the index of the response -- be 1 for demonstration purposes
i <- 1
variables <- names(mtcars)
response <- names(mtcars)[i]
predictors <- setdiff(variables, response)
model <- glm(mtcars[, get(response)] ~ mtcars[, predictors , with = FALSE], family = "gaussian")
```

However, this results to an error message:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = mtcars[, get(response)] ~
>   mtcars[,  : 
>         invalid type (list) for variable 'mtcars[, predictors, with = FALSE]'

Could you explain the error and help me correct the code?

Your advice will be appreciated.

=============================================================================

## Edit:

In reproducing the code suggested I got an error message:

```
> library(car)
> library(data.table)
> 
> data(mtcars)
> setDT(mtcars)
> model <- glm(formula = mpg ~ .,data=mtcars ,  family = "gaussian")
> vif(model)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘vif’ for signature ‘"glm"’
```

Update:

The code run without problem when I specified explicitly the package, i.e.:

```
car::vif(model)
```

## Edit 2

I had to amend Fredrik's code as follows to get the coefficients of all the variables:

```
rhs <- paste(predictors,  collapse ="+")
full_formula <- paste(response, "~", rhs)
full_formula <- as.formula(full_formula)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is based on the use of `glm.fit`:

```
model <- glm.fit(x=mtcars[, ..predictors], y=mtcars[[response]], family = gaussian())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the VIF of your predictors I would suggest looking at the `vif` function in package `car`. It will do the calculations for you and generalizes to predictors with multiple degrees of freedom such as factors.

To get all the vifs you would just hav

```
library(car)
library(data.table)

data(mtcars)
setDT(mtcars)
model <- glm(formula = mpg ~ .,data=mtcars ,  family = "gaussian")
vif(model)
```

---

As for your error, I see it as you are mixing up `glm` which takes a formula and a dataset and `glm.fit` which takes the design matrix and predictions, in that order. You have concepts from both functions in your call.

To fit your model I suggest going with the `glm` since this will give you an object of class glm with extra features such as the ability to do `plot(model)`  as opposed to `glm.fit` where you only get a list of values related to the model.

In that case you would just have to create the formula, looking something like:

```
library(data.table)

data(mtcars)
setDT(mtcars)
# Let i-- the index of the response -- be 1 for demonstration purposes
i <- 1
variables <- names(mtcars)
response <- names(mtcars)[i]
predictors <- setdiff(variables, response)


rhs <- paste(predictors, sep = " + ")
full_formula <- paste(response, "~", rhs)
model <- glm(formula = full_formula ,data=mtcars, family = "gaussian")
```

In contrast to:

```
 model <- glm.fit(y=mtcars[, get(response)] ,
                  x=mtcars[, predictors , with = FALSE],
                  family=gaussian())
```